# Image not showing up

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, content-management-system

I was trying to make a website where image can be uploaded to the database and be edited on the website like replacing the image. Whenever I try to replace the picture in the website, it gets replaced in the database but it doesn't show up in the website.

This is my PhP code.

```
if(isset($_POST['update_post'])){

    $post_author = $_POST['post_author'];
    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
                                // post_category from input
    $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category'];
    $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];
    $post_image = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");

    if(empty($post_image)) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $the_post_id ";

        $select_image = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_image)){

            $post_image = $row['post_image'];
        }
    }

    $query = "UPDATE posts SET ";
    $query .= "post_title   = '{$post_title}', ";
    $query .= "post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', ";
    $query .= "post_date    = now(), ";
    $query .= "post_author  = '{$post_author}', ";
    $query .= "post_status  = '{$post_status}', ";
    $query .= "post_tags    = '{$post_tags}', ";
    $query .= "post_content = '{$post_content}', ";
    $query .= "post_image   = '{$post_image}' ";
    $query .= "WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id} ";

    $update_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    confirm($update_query);

}
```

This the my database

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1vlW.png)

This is my website

[Website Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8mCq.png)

As you can see in the database, I have the images there but in my website, some pictures are not showing up. I want all of them to show up. Please help

Comment: Hello there people, I solved my own problem.

Comment: **Wrong Code**                                                                                                         $post_image_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];

Comment: **Correct Code** $post_image_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name']